# How to make Core Data's ManagedObjectContext.ExecuteFetchRequest Synchronous and not Asynchronous

Tags: ios, core-data, asynchronous, swift2, synchronous

Attached is my code below.

The line that is giving me the problems is `let fetchRequest = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [AppSettings]` appears to load asynchronously but I want it to load synchronously so that I can ensure it checks properly for a username record.

**How do I do this?**

I know it loads asynchronously because when I start and stop the program constantly it will find the entity roughly 80% of the time and randomly 20% of the time it will not.  Since nothing else is changing the entity (since I'm just starting and stopping the program constantly), it would make sense that the code is being run asynchrnously so when I use the command

```
guard let appSettingsArrayItem = fetchRequest.first where fetchRequest.count>0 else {
                print ("no entities found...")
                return false
            }
```

It fails to find any entities sometimes.

**Check Login Function**

```
func checkIfLoggedInAlready() -> Bool{
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AppSettings")
        //let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) //Deletes ALL appsettings entities

        do {

            let fetchRequest = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [AppSettings]

            guard let appSettingsArrayItem = fetchRequest.first where fetchRequest.count>0 else {
                print ("no entities found...")
                return false
            }

            guard let username = (appSettingsArrayItem as AppSettings).username else{
                print ("username not found")
                return false
            }

            print("number Of AppSetting Entities =\(fetchRequest.count)")
            print(username)

            //The following code deletes ALL the entities!
            //try moc.persistentStoreCoordinator!.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: moc)

            //To delete just '1' entry use the code below.

            //moc.deleteObject(appSettingsArrayItem)
            //try moc.save()//save deletion change.

            //print("deleted particular entity item")

            return true
        } catch{
            fatalError("bad things happened \(error)")
        }


    }
```

**Entire LoginViewController including Check Login Function**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    var isLoggedIn = false

    let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext

    @IBAction func SignUpButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("sign up")
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        print("view loaded, check if already signed in here")

        let loggedIn = checkIfLoggedInAlready() //checks database to see

        if(loggedIn){
            print("was logged in!")
            isLoggedIn = true

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }

    func checkIfLoggedInAlready() -> Bool{
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AppSettings")
        //let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) //Deletes ALL appsettings entities

        do {

            let fetchRequest = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [AppSettings]

            guard let appSettingsArrayItem = fetchRequest.first where fetchRequest.count>0 else {
                print ("no entities found...")
                return false
            }

            guard let username = (appSettingsArrayItem as AppSettings).username else{
                print ("username not found")
                return false
            }

            print("number Of AppSetting Entities =\(fetchRequest.count)")
            print(username)

            //The following code deletes ALL the entities!
            //try moc.persistentStoreCoordinator!.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: moc)

            //To delete just '1' entry use the code below.

            //moc.deleteObject(appSettingsArrayItem)
            //try moc.save()//save deletion change.

            //print("deleted particular entity item")

            return true
        } catch{
            fatalError("bad things happened \(error)")
        }


    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        print("prepare seque")
    }

    func displayErrorMessage(errorMessage: String){
        print("show error console with Error:"+errorMessage)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        switch(identifier){
            case "loginSegue":
                print("Is the user already logged in?")
                if(isLoggedIn){
                    print("Detected as YES")
                    return true
                }
                print("Detected as NO, so checking username and password fields next...")

                guard let password = passwordField.text!.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) where !password.isEmpty else {
                    displayErrorMessage("Password can not be empty!")
                    return false
                }

                guard let username = usernameField.text!.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) where !username.isEmpty else{
                    displayErrorMessage("Username can not be empty!")
                    return false
                }

                let url = "http://distribution.tech/restapi/v1/userlogin?email="+username+"&password="+password
                print(url)

                let json = JSON(url:url)
                print(json)

                if(json["status"].asInt==1){

                    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("AppSettings", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! AppSettings

                    entity.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
                    entity.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
                    entity.setValue(json["tokenid"].asString, forKey: "token")
                    entity.setValue(json["roleid"].asInt, forKey: "roleid")
                    entity.setValue(json["role"].asString, forKey: "role")
                    entity.setValue(json["companyid"].asInt , forKey: "companyid")
                    entity.setValue(json["isdev"].asInt, forKey: "isdev")

                    //save token and other details to database.
                    do {
                        try moc.save()
                        print("saved to entity")
                    }catch{
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }

//                    token
//                    roleid int
//                    role
//                    companyid int
//                    
//                    {
//                        "companyid": 3,
//                        "userid": 2,
//                        "tokenid": "804febae26ddbd0292b3d2c66b30afd5028d5ba9",
//                        "status": 1,
//                        "roleId": 1,
//                        "role": "super_admin",
//                        "isdev": 0
//                    }

                    //Save to disk using our own method, as COREDATA is unreliable!

                    return true //login succesfull
                }else{
                    displayErrorMessage("Incorrect Username or Email")
                    return false//failed
                }

        default:
            displayErrorMessage("Unknown Error Related To Segue Not Found")
        }
      return false //if it gets to this point assume false
    }


}
```

**The managed object is created in the DataController its file is here below.**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataController: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    override init() {
        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
        guard let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("AppSettings", withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }
        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        self.managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
            let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
            /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
            This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
            */
            let storeURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("AppSettings.sqlite")
            do {
                try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Image Reference Of Entity & Console Error That Can Happen Sometimes**

[image]

**Image Reference Of Entity & Console When It Does Find Entity Most Of Time**

[image]

Comment: Basically it's highly recommended not to give the result the same variable name as the fetch request. `executeFetchRequest` does work synchronously.

Comment: It is synchronous.  If it wasn't, there would be some mechanism to let you know when it completed (delegate, block, notification, ...).

Comment: any ideas why it will sometimes get the entities then  and sometimes not if its synchronous? Really confused what could be causing it.

Comment: @vadian I didn't even notice I used the same variable name good catch, wonder if that is causing any weird errors, will change just for good form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ManagedObjectContext.ExecuteFetchRequest` already runs synchronously but it looks like you are setting up your persistent store coordinator asynchronously in a background priority thread.

If this fetch request happens immediately when the app starts up, and you do it over and over again, it may not be finished setting up some of the times.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure it will be synchronous the persistent store coordinator? The code I used for datacontroller was copied straight from Apple, you think that is why? would make sense.

Comment: You could make your initialization function take a completion handler and call the handler from inside the block when it's done setting things up.

Comment: If you don't mind could you show me an example how that could be done? Still new to this. (even if just pointing to one online)

Answer (score 0):

Okay the answer above was correct, so what I did was created a new project single view, selected core data option, and copied code from its AppDelegate over my own AppDelegate to get the proper CoreData Init Code, and in such a way that when the project terminates it saves the context correctly and so forth.  The code looks like this.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.distribution.tech.Test" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("AppSettings", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("AppSettings.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Its key when you do this that you **change the reference to your own xcdatamodeld** or this won't work.  In my case it was changing this line to the correct sqlite based on my previous work.

```
let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("AppSettings.sqlite")
```

and this line...

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("AppSettings", withExtension: "momd")!
```

which is the actual name of the xcdatamodeld file.

Hope this helps someone who had same issue as me.  Oh...and apple if you are reading this...please add 'core data' option for tab based projects in the future... and not just single view.